# Zyan Communication Framework - Public key changed since the message was encrypted

Tags: c#, .net, rpc

I'm trying to setup a simple RPC client/server communication using the [Zyan Communication Framework](https://zyan.codeplex.com/) using a TCP duplex channel, but I keep getting the same error when the client tries to connect to the server "Public key changed since the message was encrypted".

I have explicitly set encryption to false in both client and server, so I can't see a reason for that error.

For demonstration purposes, I have setup a sample demonstrating the problem

Versions:

- NET version 4.5.2
- Zyan 2.6.2

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Zyan.Communication;
using Zyan.Communication.Protocols.Tcp;

namespace StackOverflowMinimalSample
{
    public interface ISampleService
    {
        string GetGreeting();
    }

    public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public string GetGreeting()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 5252;
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var protocol = new TcpDuplexServerProtocolSetup(port){Encryption = false};
                using (var tcpHost = new ZyanComponentHost("TCPCommunication", protocol))
                {
                    tcpHost.RegisterComponent<ISampleService, SampleService>();

                    Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            })
            {IsBackground = true};
            serverThread.Start();

            Thread clientThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                // Sleep for a while to give time to the server
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                var protocol = new TcpDuplexClientProtocolSetup(encryption: false);
                var url = protocol.FormatUrl("127.0.0.1", port, "TCPCommunication");

                try
                {
                    using (var connection = new ZyanConnection(url))
                    {
                        ISampleService proxy = connection.CreateProxy<ISampleService>();
                        string serverMessage = proxy.GetGreeting();

                        Console.WriteLine("Server message: " + serverMessage);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // This will throw here.
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: " + e.Message);
                }

            })
            {IsBackground = true};
            clientThread.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://zyan.codeplex.com/discussions/453233

"you're using duplex TCP channel to connect within the same AppDomain. TcpEx channel doesn't support this by design.

Please use either IpcBinary channel or NullChannel to connect within the same application domain."